# Why is my UIAlertController not being fired?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to display a `UIAlertController` whenever user opens the application.

This is how I'm creating and trying to show it:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //simple alert dialog
        let alert=UIAlertController(title: "Alert 1", message: "One is awesome", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        //show it
        showViewController(alert, sender: self);

    }
}
```

Why is it not being displayed?

Comment: what exactly is `showViewController`?

Comment: It's a default method to display the UIAlertController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work if  you'd use:  `presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`

As @matt stated, it’s better to present your alertViewController in ViewDidAppear instead of ViewDidLoad, because than the presenting viewController is in the interface.

Comment: I replaced and it doesn`t show up anything. I think you meant viewDidAppear

Comment: Ah sorry I was testing it with `presentViewController` instead of `showViewController`, which does work in viewDidLoad. I've updated my answer

Comment: Sorry but I have to downvote this. You should not be doing this presentation in `viewDidLoad`. There is no interface yet. It may appear to work, but that's kind of accidental.

Answer (score 2):

Too soon. In `viewDidLoad`, your view is not even in the interface yet! There is nothing to `show` from.

Comment: Where should I put it then? If I change a label text there, for example, it works.

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is the usual place, but then be careful not to trigger the alert in the future when you don't want to.